# ORM: Sequelize: many to many relationship

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

1. Do I have to do two table modeling to create a many to many relationship in sequelize? Do I have three?
2. If I only model two tables, can I use `belongsTo()`?
3. Should I use `belongsToMany()` if I model three tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have two tables with a many to many relationship then you must have a join table, that would result in you needing three models to set sequelize up properly with the belongsToMany associations on both sides

Comment: e.g. If you have a product or category, does it mean you need three models, even a product_category table?

Comment: Yes, if it is many to many meaning if a category can have many products and a product can belong to multiple categories then yes you need a product_category join table.... if a product can only belong to one category then you would not need the join table, you could have a hasMany and a belongsTo instead and have a category_id column in the product table

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a question here, and I would appreciate it too.